# Source code control tab doesn't show files

Tags: visual-studio-code

The problem is this: source control tab doesn't show any files regardless if they were modified, deleted, etc. Git works fine, VS code buttons work fine everything else works, I wonder, if vs code update broke it, since I haven't change anything
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBv6u.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDyy4.png)

I have tried:
reload VS code,
reinstall VS code (somehow all my settings and extensions survive)
reboot Windows
start VS code with all extensions disabled

didn't help

Comment: 1) are those files in your .gitignore or `files.exclude` setting? 2) please paste the version info _as text_- not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL-SHIFT-P

> View: Reset View Locations

has helped